# Using multiple loops to make a permutation of the values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries. `A` is empty and `B` is a dictionary that is something I want to feed into `A`, but I should feed different values in a different loop.

```
A = {'format': None,
     'items' : None,
     'status' : None,
     'name': None}

B = {'format': 'json',
     'items' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     'status' : [1, 2, 3],
     'name': 'test'}
```

I have a stupid method to get this answer, but actually I want something like this:

```
while not finish:
    for key, values in B.items():
        if type(values) != list:
            A[key] = values
        else :
            for items in values:
                A[key] = items
                # do something here
```

But it seems this can't achieve the targets I want, i.e.:
A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3 ... C-3

First iteration:

```
A = {'format': 'json',
     'items' : 'A',
     'status' : 1,
     'name': 'test'}
```

Second iteration:

```
A = {'format': 'json',
     'items' : 'A',
     'status' : 2,
     'name': 'test'}
```

and so on...

Final iteration:

```
A = {'format': 'json',
     'items' : 'C',
     'status' : 3,
     'name': 'test'}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Use `pandas`:

#### Given `B` as shown in the question:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

B = {'format': ['json'],
     'items' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     'status' : [1, 2, 3],
     'name': ['test']}

df = pd.DataFrame(product(*(v for _, v in B.items())), columns=B.keys())
```

#### Now the data is in a form useful for further analysis:

```py
  format items  status  name
0   json     A       1  test
1   json     A       2  test
2   json     A       3  test
3   json     B       1  test
4   json     B       2  test
5   json     B       3  test
6   json     C       1  test
7   json     C       2  test
8   json     C       3  test
```

#### Data can easily be saved to a file:

```
df.to_json('test.json')
```

```
{'format': {0: 'json', 1: 'json', 2: 'json', 3: 'json', 4: 'json', 5: 'json', 6: 'json', 7: 'json', 8: 'json'},
 'items': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'C', 8: 'C'},
 'name': {0: 'test', 1: 'test', 2: 'test', 3: 'test', 4: 'test', 5: 'test', 6: 'test', 7: 'test', 8: 'test'},
 'status': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3}}
```

#### Data can be read back in:

```
df1 = pd.read_json('test.json')
```

---

### With `list comprehension` - no `pandas`:

#### if all the `values` in `B` are `lists`:

```
B = {'format': ['json'],
     'items' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     'status' : [1, 2, 3],
     'name': ['test']}

list_dicts = [dict(zip(B.keys(), x)) for x in product(*(v for _, v in B.items()))]
```

#### if `values` in `B` are `str`:

```
B = {'format': 'json',
     'items' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     'status' : [1, 2, 3],
     'name': 'test'}

list_dicts = [dict(zip(B.keys(), x)) for x in product(*([v] if type(v) == str else v for _, v in B.items()))]
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need `A`, just the values you'd like to iterate over, and use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

items = ['A', 'B', 'C']
status = [1, 2, 3]

for i, s in product(items, status):
    print({'format': 'json',
           'items' : i,
           'status' : s,
           'name': 'test'})
```

Outputs

```
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'A', 'status': 1, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'A', 'status': 2, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'A', 'status': 3, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'B', 'status': 1, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'B', 'status': 2, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'B', 'status': 3, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'C', 'status': 1, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'C', 'status': 2, 'name': 'test'}
{'format': 'json', 'items': 'C', 'status': 3, 'name': 'test'}
```